# Prevent menu animation transition on page load

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm building a menu with an "indicator" just like this codepen: https://codepen.io/jnowland/pen/XmQGNx

Everything works perfectly except for one little tiny detail: When the link is clicked and that page loads, the indicator animates from the previous child before settling on the link that just became .active. This can't be seen in the linked example, only the hover effect. This is a screen recording of my menu (sorry for the low gif framerate):
[image: Screen recording of css menu]

You can see how the hover works perfectly but note how the transition jumps from the menu item before after a link is clicked and that page loads. I don't want a transition here. How can I prevent that? My code looks almost exactly the same as the codepen for the parts that control this so please refer to the code in the link.

```
.Nav-item {
    &:last-child {
      &:before, &:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: left #{$transition-speed} ease;
      }
```

My initial thought was deleting the transition from this part but it messes up the whole transition so it has to stay.

```
.Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}).is-active ~ .Nav-item:last-child:before
    {
      left:($width*$i)+($width/2)-$width;
```

```
.Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}):hover ~ .Nav-item:last-child:before{
      left:($width*$i)+($width/2)-$width !important;
    }
```

Adding the transition inside these two and delete from the first code block doesn't seem to be the right way to go either.

Comment: Which CSS pre-processor are you using? Please add the relevant tag to the question.

Comment: The codepen I've linked to use SASS, but I don't use any pre-processor. I had to break out the SASS variables and loops and write plain CSS in my project. I need to stay pure CSS as I'm stuck with MonoSolutions wysiwyg online editor. I can only edit CSS in their module

Comment: Without knowing exactly why the menu is persistent, it's a bit hard to tell. I'm no CSS god though. One trick I use for situations where I can't use Javascript is to use a form ratio and ":checked" It's got me through a few scrapes. https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: @AnyDay Thanks, I'm going to try the checkbox-hack and see if I can get what I want. I will have to use JavaScript to append the checkbox under each li element. We'll see if it makes a difference with that approach...

Answer (score 0):

After days of trial and error I accidentally jumped over what I now think is why the menu is persistent and displays this error:

On page load, the tool I work with (MonoSolutions) adds a separate li item first in the list for the swipe menu close button, but it is set to hide for all screen sizes above mobile. This hidden state takes a fraction of a second to load and just before that happens, all nth-child(#) is one step behind. The unwanted transition is seen when the first list item hides.

Note: The code is probably correct, if you'd work outside a stupid WYSIWYG editor.